# date picker code in html

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

we tried the code  for displaying date using date picker it should display two times in a single page for from and to dates,but it is displaying only for from date and not for to date

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-css'  href='admin.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-fresh-css'  href='colors-fresh.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $("#icon").click(function() { 
            $("#datepicker").datepicker( "show" );
        })
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name='from' size='9' value="" />  
    <img src='images/calender.PNG' id='icon' height='25px' width='25px'/ >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to have to input fields for both fromdate and todate

Comment: I can see only 'from' input[=text], you need to have 'to' input[=text] to view the To.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but there's no "to" input in your example?

Comment: There's only one datepicker element in your current code...

Comment: maybe he forget adding other input? that what I was thinking ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you use input type date

```
<input type="date" id="datepicker" name='from' size='9' value="" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PRXMz/3/)**

Comment: Make sure the type="date" is supports in HTML5.

Comment: Because it's not currently supported outside of opera and chrome: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime (Hey, the specs have only been around for years and years and years...)

Answer (score 0):

Your body does not contain a second `<input>` Tag to attach a datepicker to.

So use something like this.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker_from" name='from' size='9' value="" />  <img src='images/calender.PNG' id='icon_from' height='25px' width='25px'/ >
<input type="text" id="datepicker_to" name='from' size='9' value="" />  <img src='images/calender.PNG' id='icon_to' height='25px' width='25px'/ >
```

And in your JS Code:

```
$( "#datepicker_from" ).datepicker();
$("#icon_from").click(function() { $("#datepicker_from").datepicker( "show" );})

$( "#datepicker_to" ).datepicker();
$("#icon_to").click(function() { $("#datepicker_to").datepicker( "show" );})
```

One advice: Prevent using IDs over IDs. It's hard to maintain. If you want to achieve the same thing on different DOM Elements, it's better to use class selectors, like @Pathik Gandhi showed in his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545224/735226

Some additional notes:

Wrap your own javascript around the DOM ready event to prevent that your js is executing before your DOM finished loading. You can achieve this by the following piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Place all of your JS code here, like your datepicker initializing.
});
```

Also load your Javascript right before the end of the `<body>` tag to improving loading speed:

```
    /* ... */
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
```

Those are just some general advice for structured web development.

Answer (score 0):

Just add two input from and to with same class and date picker has inbuilt functionality to show icon.

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
           $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
              showOn: "button",
              buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
              buttonImageOnly: true
            });
    });   

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name='from' size='9' value="" />
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" name='to' size='9' value="" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two input fields if you want two datepickers

```
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="fromdate" name='from' size='9' value="" />
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="todate" name='from' size='9' value="" />

$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rPYax/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using class instead of id. ID should be unique and if its not then you will find yourself in trouble. Using class give you oportunity to work with many elements having the same class, in case of id it will process correctly for 1 id and will give not wanted results for others not mentioning it may cause other problems.  Try this

```
$(function()
            {
                     $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
                     $(".icon").click(function() { $(".datepicker").datepicker( "show" );})
             });

 <input type="text" class="datepicker" name='from' size='9' value="" />  <img src='images/calender.PNG' class='icon' height='25px' width='25px'/ > 

 <input type="text" class="datepicker" name='to' size='9' value="" />  <img src='images/calender.PNG' class='icon' height='25px' width='25px'/ >
```

Also check html5 date and datetime type example here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$(function(){
    $( "#from_date,$to_date" ).datepicker();        
});
```

and your html should be

```
<input type="text" id="from_date">
<input type="text" id="to_date">
```

that's it